# Springdata Neo4j primary key

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and SDN . I was trying to create a primary key for my entities using @Indexed(unique=true). It creates unique nodes but will replace the other properties if i used the same property value which is indexed.
Eg:

```
Class abc{
@Indexed(unique=true)
Long abc_id;
String abc_name;
}

new abc(1,"asd")// creates node with id: 1 name : asd
new abc(1,"xyz")// replaces asd with xyz .
```

However I want to throw an exception about primary key violation/duplicate node.

Is there some method to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the @Indexed implementation doesnt throw any exception for any duplicates as quoted in this JIRA ticket on the spring data neo4j forum : [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-445) and in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362767/spring-data-neo4j-repository-save-and-indexedunique-true)

You may create unique nodes running cypher queries (which will be faster). You can use [MERGE](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-merge.html) to create or update nodes.

From the documentation

```
MERGE either matches existing nodes and binds them, or it creates new data and binds that. It’s like a combination of MATCH and CREATE that additionally allows you to specify what happens if the data was matched or created.
```

So you can do something like below if you want to update any node or create a node if that pattern doesnt exist.

```
MERGE (keanu:Person { name:'Keanu Reeves' })
ON CREATE SET keanu.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET keanu.lastSeen = timestamp()
RETURN keanu
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So using MERGE is the only way to achieve this or for Spring-data-neo4j there is some alternate solution.

Comment: check out that thread attached in the answer.. the guy has tried several ways to achieve it but i prefer creating using merge..

Comment: To create or update nodes using MERGE,do you use Query annotation in SDN or Core JAVA API.I have this doubt as I read that the core JAVA API is better in some cases compared to SDN. I have created a SDN Project and use repositories to interact with the DB. Will it be better to use Neo4jTemplate instead of repositories.Thanks in advance.